# Mathematica Discord Server chat

Tags: discussion, chat

I've started an unoficial server here: https://discord.gg/gj6VKAK on Discord for talking live about the Wolfram Language / Mathematica.

If you don't know what Discord is, see here: https://discordapp.com/

Comment: I am not familiar with Discord. What tangible advantages would bring compared to SE chat?